# SpatialIndexProvider in Neo4jclient for Geospatial Searches

Tags: geospatial, neo4jclient

Is support for the neo4j spatial plugin on the roadmap?  If not is there a workable solution for adding items via a SpatialIndexProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the lead of the Neo4jClient project, I can say that this is no currently on our roadmap.

There's no particular reason for that beyond the fact that I don't use it personally and nobody has asked previously.

To make it happen, your best options are:

1) Create an issue on https://bitbucket.org/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues
2) Describe the expected impact
3) Even better, send a pull request

In the meantime, you can obviously do direct REST calls for the indexing operations but keep everything else going via Neo4jClient.

Finally, it should be noted that our general direction is to support Cypher more and more. It would be good to align to any Cypher+Spatial plans, if they exist.